# Which DB to connect to for higher level application managing other database

Tags: sql, asp.net, postgresql

I have an application that will be creating and dropping postgres databases. The application itself has its own sql server database. Kind of a bizarre architecture but it's not by choice.

I'm a little confused on how I should connect to the postgres server to execute these create table and drop table commands. Normally in an `app.config` or `web.config`, the connection string would specify the database. In this case, I just want to specify the server.

Can queries be run directly to a postgres server, without a particular database?

Should I use the `postgres` database that was created by the server? I tried this... `select * from pg_database` and then `drop database DBNAME` with a result from the first query, and it gave an error saying the database does not exist.

Or I could create an empty database to connect to and submit the queries to it, despite it not being used for anything.

Comment: Extremely bizarre, like "why would you ever do that" bizarre.

Comment: As for the error, show the *actual query* and the *exact error message* please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could connect to the *postgres* database and then run `drop database <DBNAME>` from there, yes. Another option would be, say, *template1*. (I would avoid *template0* since that's essentially the root template from which *template1* was created, and you could always recreate *template1* quickly from *template0* if something happened to it, assuming you haven't modified *template1* but not *template0*.)

I usually connect to *postgres*, myself, for server-level commands.

I ran `DROP DATABASE droptest;` via *psql* after creating an empty database and seeing it returned from a `pg_database` query, so that definitely works in general.

Perhaps it was somehow deleted via some other process in the interim between when you queried things and when you did the `DROP...`.

Another option would be to shell out to the command line tool [*dropdb*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropdb.html) instead. This is a wrapper around `drop database` and is what I generally use both for manual and automated instances of database drops.

Answer (score 4):

> Can queries be run directly to a postgres server, without a particular database?

No. PostgreSQL requires that you connect to a specific database.

It's possible that restriction could actually be relaxed eventually, so you could do things that only work on the shared catalogs from a connection to no particular database. It'd require changes to how authentication works and all sorts of things, though, and I don't think having an "admin database" like the usually-empty `postgres` database is really a problem.

> Should I use the postgres database that was created by the server?

Generally, yes. It's possible to `DROP` the `postgres` database, but you should usually just leave it alone and use it as an admin database.